# Escaping # in BRE regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to find files that are scripts and I need to get from these files the list of all interpreters like Bash, sh, etc.

To find that, I use:

```
grep "#!/bin/*" ./*
```

But it displays that:

```
-bash: !/bin/*": event not found
```

I assume I need to escape # symbol somehow, but I didn't find that symbol to be escaped in documentation of BRE.

And how I can find files that contain this pattern in regex only on the first line of the file?

Comment: Note that you can disable [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) by using `set +H`, which can for example be added to your `.bash_rc`. I won't post this as an answer because you shouldn't rely on it for your script to work, but since I find this feature annoying I like to disable it for myself.

Answer (score 2):

- the `#` is no problem, you should escape the `!`, in Bash it refers to **a** previous command and must be followed by something, `$` for the previous command or a number representing the index of the command in the history. (thx Aaron's correction)
- also you may want to change `*` into `.*`

like `grep "#\!/bin/.*"`

- If you don't want to escape  `!`, use single quote like:

  ```
  grep '#!/bin' ....
  ```

Also you can disable the `regex` match by using `-F`

Comment: @Aaron you're absolutely right! `The` here is confusing. I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: You're welcome ! Thanks for crediting me but there's really no need :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following find command and let me know if this helps.

```
 find -type f -exec grep -l '#!/bin*' {} \+
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `!` with `\`:

```
grep "#\!/bin/*" ./*
```